# Python - Finding and multiplying an integer after specific word

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I have a text file that has over 60,000 lines in it and I need to go through and find a specific word and then multiply the number after it. For example:

```
The cat jumped over the log
  tree 6
the dog also jumped over the log
tree 43
```

Would end up, if multiplying by 2, as:

```
The cat jumped over the log
  tree 12
the dog also jumped over the log
tree 86
```

I know this is fairly simple to do but I can't wrap my head around it. I need to step through the whole text file word by word looking for instances of "tree ", finding the integer after this, making the change, and then replacing the line.

I also know that every occurrence of "tree " will always have an integer next to it.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

Current code I have as of now is:

```
file = open('export_desc.txt', 'r')

a = "ext_mpl "
for line in file:
    n = file.find(a+1)
    n = n*2
    file.write(line.replace(a+1, a+n))

file.close()
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have written so far?

Comment: `file = open('export_desc.txt', 'r')

a = "ext_mpl "
for line in file:
    n = file.find(a+1)
    n = n*2
    file.write(line.replace(a+1, a+n))

file.close()`

Comment: Please add it in the description itself, so that all can see it..

Comment: Woops, sorry, adding now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even have to write a python script, a `sed` command can help you:

```
sed -r '/^tree ([0-9]+)$/{h;s/^.* ([0-9]+)$/echo \1*2|bc/e;H;g;s/[0-9]+\n//}' export_desc.txt
```

Sample:

```
>sed -r '/^tree ([0-9]+)$/{h;s/^.* ([0-9]+)$/echo \1*2|bc/e;H;g;s/[0-9]+\n//}' 123
The cat jumped over the log
tree 12
the dog also jumped over the log
tree 86
>cat 123
The cat jumped over the log
tree 6
the dog also jumped over the log
tree 43
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to rewrite a file in-place. You can use `print` to write back to the same file (but do strip the newlines), or write to `sys.stdout` (with the newlines left in place):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('filename', inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line.strip().startswith('tree '):
        start, value = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        line = '{} {}'.format(start, (int(value) * 2)

    print line
```

[`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes whitespace (tabs, spaces, carriage returns, newlines, etc.) from the start and end of the line, allowing for more tolerance in testing for `tree` at the start of a line.

The [`str.rsplit()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) splits the line on the last section of whitespace, assuming the number is the last thing on the line. The `None` argument makes `.rsplit()` split on arbitrary-width whitespace, and the `1` makes it split just once. This results in two return values; the start of the line up to the last section of whitespace, and the number.

This allows us to reconstruct the original line, mostly, with the value doubled.

Comment: Nothing seems to be changing in the file. I forgot to mention that there is indentation before some of the words "tree " which is of course preventing the startswith() method from working. Is there anyway to do this but temporarily ignore the whitespace? The whitespace before "tree " isn't always uniform, so including the whitespace in the string won't work.

Comment: @nexatt: sure, use `line.strip().startswith('tree ')`. `str.strip()` removes arbitrary-width whitespace from the start and end of the line.

Comment: @nexatt: should the leading indentation be preserved on output?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be. Additionally, I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't split()[-1] only work if the number following tree was single digits? What if the number was 2 or more digits?

Comment: `.split()` splits on (arbitrary width) whitespace and returns a *list*; `[-1]` takes the last element from the list.

Comment: Ah, I see. So how could I use this to retain the whitespace? `line.strip().startswith('tree ')` works perfectly, however it destroys the whitespace in front of it. Sorry for all the questions - I learned the very basics of Python years ago and I'm struggling to remember what I had learned now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I missed your edit in your original post. This works fantastically - thank you!